# "Date has wrong format" Angular 10 Rest Django

Tags: django-rest-framework, datepicker, angular-material, date-format, angular10

Hi I'm new to these two frameworks and I need your help !

So I'm using Rest Django for backend and Angular for Frontent , I'm also using Angular material for the DatePicker , although I changed the format of the date to YYYY-MM-DD to the DatePicker I still receive an error message "Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DD." by the server when sending the api !

to change the date format in Angular I used this code into app.module

```
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MomentDateModule, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

export const DateFormats = {
            parse: {
                dateInput: ['YYYY-MM-DD']
            },
            display: {
                dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                monthYearLabel: 'MM YYYY',
                dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
                monthYearA11yLabel: 'MM YYYY',
            },
        };
providers: [
          { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
          { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DateFormats }
  ],
```

After console.log('date',this.date) to see the date object entered by the datepicker I received

```
date 
{…}
​
_d: Date Tue Aug 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (UTC+01:00)
​
_i: Object { year: 2020, month: 7, date: 18 }
​
_isAMomentObject: true
​
_isUTC: false
​
_isValid: true
​
_locale: Object { _calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", … }
​
_pf: Object { empty: false, overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 0, … }
​
<prototype>: Object { add: createAdder(val, period), calendar: calendar$1(time, formats), clone: clone(), … }
```

Do you know how can I solve the problem please ?

Comment: What is the actual request content?  Look in your network tab at the request and see what is actually being sent.

Comment: error 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyProjects/project/", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyProjects/project/: 400 Bad Request", error: {…} }

Comment: error 
{…}
​
error: {…}
​​
datefin: Array [ "Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DD." ]

Comment: these are what I received do you know what is the probleme ?

Comment: 2020-08-18   this was the date I add on date picker as you see it's also YYYY-MM-DD thank you for your interest

Comment: Please edit your post, and add the contents of the *request body* that is posted.  This will be in json format.

Answer (score 0):

u should create a method to trim ur date removing the timezone & other inform then call the method in ur date input field
something like this
yourDateApp.component.ts file

```
trimDate(myDate){
  let strDate = JSON.stringfy(myDate.value)
  let newDate = strDate.substring(1, 11)
  //assign the new trimmed date to date value in ur form
  yourForm.controls['date_field'].setValue(newDate)
}
```

yourDateApp.component.html file
//call your function in the html file like this

```
<input matInput (dateChange)="trimDate($event)">
```

this will accept the date trim it to a way django will recognize it